#  Definition of "closure under isomorphism"

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does " Closed Under Isomorphism " means ? 
why do we need it ?
And how can we use it in " Mathematical Structures" 
thanks

Comment: I have never heard that phrase used before.

Comment: Now you heard about it :)

Comment: Why is this tagged `(data-analysis)`? What do you mean by mathematical structure? Can you provide definitions?

Comment: It was by mistake , I could not change it

Comment: Set $X$ is closed under an $n$-ary operator $\ast$ if for all $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in X,$ we have $\ast(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n) \in X.$ That is, the result of applying the operator is an element of $X.$ Examples of the non-closure: $\mathbb{Q}$ under $\sqrt{\cdots}.$ We have $2\in \mathbb{Q}$ but $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: @Mohammed: It would help if you could provide an excerpt or link to the place where this terminology was used.

Comment: www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/ASM/Nondeterminism.pptx
slid 3

Comment: If you can't read PPTX, here's a Google docs viewer link https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.cs.tau.ac.il%2F~nachumd%2FASM%2FNondeterminism.pptx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody answered this question I will give it a try.
I encountered closure under isomorphism in the definition of a *Markov property* in group theory (doesn't correspond to the *Markov property* I find on Wikipedia). One of the requirements for a property of groups $\mathcal{B}$ to be a *Markov property* is that it is closed under isomorphism
$$
\mathcal{B}\text{ is true for a group }G\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{B}\text{ is true for every group isomorphic to }G
$$
Most (arguably all) properties one considers in group theory (finite, abelian, ...) are closed under group isomorphism.

So I would generally define a property $\mathcal{B}$ of objects in a category $\mathcal{C}$ to be closed under isomorphism iff 
$$
\mathcal{B}\text{ is true for }A\in\mathcal{C}\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{B}\text{ is true for every object in }\mathcal{C}\text{ isomorphic to }A
$$

Comment: Isn't this more commonly called "invariant under isomorphism" or "preserved under isomorphism"?

Comment: @jwodder: True, I would probably also use "preserved under isomorphism". Andrew Glass, who taught a course on decision problems in group theory last year, used "closed under isomorphism".

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction to the phrase is that it would be used in a context such as

The category $\mathcal{C}$ is a subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$. We say that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under isomorphism iff:

If $f : X \to Y$ is an arrow of $\mathcal{C}$ and $g : Y \to Z$ and $h : W \to X$ are both isomorphisms in $\mathcal{D}$, then $gf$ and $fh$ are both arrows of $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the statement:

For any isomorphism-closed class of finite structures, there is a first-order theory that defines it.

That is:

A property of finite structures is any isomorphism-closed class of structures.

So:
Any class of finite structures closed under isomorphisms is axiomatised by a
first-order theory.